# How to make a base of a folder in a url go to a page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, blogs

I want to make `www.example.com/blog/` go to a page `blog.php` that has all my blog posts but still works as a folder: `www.example.com/blog/blog-post/`.

When I try to do this I get an internal server error because it thinks I am trying to access the folder itself instead `blog.php` (I removed the .php file extension in htaccess)

How can I do this without renaming the folder? I also want to do this for translations (`www.example.com/es/` is the homepage in Spanish, but `www.example.com/es/example` is a page within the folder `es`. TIA.

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^blog\/$ "https\:\/\/www\.georgerflint\.com\/blog" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: show your .htaccess code.

Comment: @AmitRajput here's all the code that isn't totally irrelevant stuff

Comment: You want to redirect rule or rewrite rule here?

Comment: @AmitRajput either as long as the url shows the folder at base being a page